# jQuery equivalent to insertNode?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on converting a pure JS text highlight script to jQuery, but I'm trying to figure out what the jQuery equivalent to `insertNode` is:

```
var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
span.appendChild(selectedText);
selection.insertNode(span);
```

I figured I could use the following:

```
var span = $("<span class='highlight'>" + selectedText + "</span>");
selection.insertNode(span);
```

Which results in:

```
NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.
```

Comment: If the JavaScript works, why are you converting it?

Comment: The rest of my page is in jQuery, so I want it to be uniform.

Comment: __jQuery is JavaScript__.

Comment: I never claimed it wasn't.

Comment: yeah, I can understand the desire for uniformity. It's so much nicer to use jQuery chains that don't have to break to insert "regular" javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think jQuery can operate on selections, you'll have to use the regular JS methods. You're getting an error because your `span` is a jQuery object, not a node.

Also, `selection.extractContents()` will return a DocumentFragment, not a string. So try this:

```
var selection = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectedText = selection.extractContents();
var span = $("<span class='highlight'>" + selectedText.textContent + "</span>");
selection.insertNode(span[0]); // pass the first node in the jQuery object
```

Comment: That inserts `[object DocumentFragment]`... hmm

Comment: How about span[0].firstChild?

Comment: I must have missed this: The original inserts `<span>[object DocumentFragment]</span>` while the comment inserts just `[object DocumentFragment]`

Comment: Wait, the DocumentFragment is actually your `selectedText`, not span[0]

Comment: Yes, but `var span` is `("<span class='highlight'>" + selectedText + "</span>");`

Comment: I'm suggesting selectedText.textContent, see the code I just added to the answer. You can test it on this very page, select something and paste that code into the console.

Comment: really? what about on IE? what about innerText? what about try text()?

Comment: I have the luxury of not caring about IE ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use prepend() or append() or insertAfter() or insertAt()

$(selection).append();

Comment: Using `selection.append(span)` results in `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'selection.append(span)')`

Comment: @Charlie: You can only use jQuery methods on jQuery objects.

Comment: Your edit results in `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'context.createDocumentFragment()')`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to insert the element, not the jQuery object:

```
selection.insertNode(span[0]);
```